# Reading csv from windows C drive in Azure databricks

Tags: windows, csv, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a `.csv` file from windows `C` drive to databricks. I tried the following code after going through some of the answers.

```
# remove the 'file' string and use 'r' or 'u' prefix to indicate raw/unicore string format
# Option 1
#PATH = r'C:\customers_marketing.csv'  # raw string
# Option 2
PATH = u'C:\\customers_marketing.csv' # unicode string
customers_marketing = spark.read.csv(PATH, header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

However, I was not able to read it to databricks. I get the following error.

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5Ccustomers_marketing.csv
```

Could anyone pls advise/suggest how can I read data from windows c drive to databricks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, because your file is on your local machine, and Databricks is in the cloud, without any knowledge about your machine.

You need to upload file onto DBFS, and then read from it.  You can do it for example via UI - via DBFS file browser ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#browse-dbfs-using-the-ui)) or via Upload Data UI ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data))

If the file is huge, then you need to use something like [az-copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) to upload file(s) to Azure Storage

Comment: thanks Alex. but i have 20GB data and i assume limit is only 2GB to upload thats why this is a blocker for me. can not think of any other solution

Comment: I've updated answer - for big files you need to use something like az-copy